# Filling pandas DataFrame up to first data point and from last data point with given values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Take the following test dataframe:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a' : [np.nan, np.nan, 4.0, 5.0, 12.0, 45.0, 86.0, 92.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
test_df

    col_a
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   4.0
3   5.0
4   12.0
5   45.0
6   86.0
7   92.0
8   NaN
9   NaN
10  NaN
```

Now I want to fill all NAs in `col_a` up to the first data point (4.0) with the value 0.0.

I also want to replace all NAs from the latest data point (92.0) with the value of 100.0.

Combinations of keywords `value` and `method` of the [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method don't seem to work as I first hoped.

Can you help? The more pythonic, the better. Thank you.

**++++++++**

**EDIT**

Indeed, I can start by fill the top of the dataframe as follows:

```
test_df.loc[0:test_df['col_a'].first_valid_index()] = test_df.loc[0:test_df['col_a'].first_valid_index()].fillna(value=0)
```

And then use the `fillna` method to replace NAs left, but it is quite ugly and difficult to handle with countless columns and other dataframe constraints.

**++++++++**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign values by helper Series created by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) of max created by `cumsum` and then create masks by compare by `min` and `max`, but for max is necessary [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) for omit last non `NaN` value:

```
a = test_df['col_a'].notnull().cumsum()
print (a)
0     0
1     0
2     1
3     2
4     3
5     4
6     5
7     6
8     6
9     6
10    6
Name: col_a, dtype: int32

test_df[a == a.min()] = 0
test_df[a.shift() == a.max()] = 100
print (test_df)
    col_a
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     4.0
3     5.0
4    12.0
5    45.0
6    86.0
7    92.0
8   100.0
9   100.0
10  100.0
```